# Shell commands within if-block of gnuplot

Tags: if-statement, gnuplot

I want to execute shell commands inside if-block of Gnuplot. I tried the following:

```
datatype = 'full'

if ( datatype eq 'full' ) {
    # Run shell command
    !echo 'full'
} else {
    # Run different shell command
    !echo 'not full'
}
```

However, this gives me the error `"filename.plt" line xx: invalid command`

FYI, I already know instead of `!echo`, I can use `print` to do the same thing. That's not the point. I want to use shell commands with the symbol `!` within the if-block. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `system` instead of `!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@choroba has given the correct solution: use the `system("command")` function instead of `!command`.

As to why this is necessary, in brief:

(1) The `!` operator is interpreted as indicating a shell command only if it is the first token on a gnuplot input line. Otherwise it is interpreted as a logical `NOT`.

(2) Gnuplot bracketed clauses `{ lots of commands }` are treated internally as a single long input line.  This is an implementation detail that has changed over time.  The safest general guideline is that a bracketed clause should not contain any syntax that is documented as acting on or affecting a single line of input. This includes `@` macro substitution, single-line if statements, and as you found, the `!` operator.

(1+2) Therefor a `!` inside a bracketed clause is not seen as being the first token, and is interpreted as a logical `NOT` operator instead.